# How to add jquery in php file which works on ajax call

Tags: php, jquery

I want to add jquery code in php file which loads data in ajax call.

My jquery code is showing when ajax response loaded in done function but not working.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: there are different ways to carry the action you named. no one can help you before your way is known.

Comment: $custompanel .= "<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $(window).bind('load', function() { { 
     alert('hi'); 
     
  });
});
</script>";

Comment: i have add this code in my php file from where the form fields append on other page with ajax responce

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to call AJAX on php is:

HTML :

```
<script>
function showHint(str) {
    if (str.length == 0) { 
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "gethint.php?q=" + str, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
</script>
```

and your PHP response file should be something similar to this:

gethint.php :

```
<?php
// Array with names
$a[] = "Anna";
$a[] = "Brittany";
$a[] = "Liza";
$a[] = "Elizabeth";

// get the q parameter from URL
$q = $_REQUEST["q"];

$hint = "";

// lookup all hints from array if $q is different from "" 
if ($q !== "") {
    $q = strtolower($q);
    $len=strlen($q);
    foreach($a as $name) {
        if (stristr($q, substr($name, 0, $len))) {
            if ($hint === "") {
                $hint = $name;
            } else {
                $hint .= ", $name";
            }
        }
    }
}

// Output "no suggestion" if no hint was found or output correct values 
echo $hint === "" ? "no suggestion" : $hint;
?>
```

the script check the php file for response and then return the value to your script for any usage. you should do server side process inside php file.

Answer (score 0):

You can add JQuery AJAX like this in your php file.

```
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("button").click(function(){
    $.ajax({url: "demo_test.txt", success: function(result){
        $("#div1").html(result);
    }});
});
});
</script>
```